# Custom fields in Liferay users CSV export have null values

Tags: csv, null, export, liferay, custom-fields

I need to add some custom fields to the user export in CSV. I defined the fields in portal-ext.properties but then when I restarted and returned to the Users portlet in Control Panel the columns for my custom fields contained only null values. Did anyone manage to fix this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Gruess dich, Christian,

What you're talking about is caused by a bug in Liferay 6.0.6. It should have been fixed in newer versions. You can fix this following instructions [here](http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/exporting-user-custom-fields-in-csv.html) - a blog post that describes where to find and how to fix the bug.

http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/exporting-user-custom-fields-in-csv.html

Cheers!!!